# When moving files in PyCharm, is there a way to automatically update references to that file?

Tags: pycharm

I am refactoring some code and want my references to outdated file paths to update to the new file paths. I don't see any such option in the move dialog. what can I do?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any way to do that after the fact.

The only way I know how to do this is to select the file, then Refactor -> Move (from the drop down or context menu) and make sure the "Search for references" box is checked. It'll show you in the search window all the places in code that will be updated as part of the refactor.

I've only used PyCharm with a decent sized Django project and it has done really well with finding references.